# Background processes mix up order of shell script execution

Tags: shell, shell-script, background-process, echo, concurrency

Can someone explain me why the script

```
echo one && 
echo two & 
echo three && 
echo four
```

gives me

```
[1] 3692
three
four
one
two
[1]+  Done                    echo one && echo two
```

Apparently everything behind the background process is outputted first and the lines of code chronologically before the background process are printed last. I stumbled upon it in a script I tried to write and don't get why it behaves like this (althogh I guess there is some ingenuity behind it).

I already found out that I can prevent this with brackets:

```
echo one && 
(echo two &) 
echo three && 
echo four
```

gives

```
one
two
three
four
```

and

```
echo one && 
(sleep 2 && echo two &)
echo three && 
echo four
```

gives

```
one
three
four
two
```

Because line two sleeps in the background and hence outputs when the first lines have already been executed.

But why do brackets have this effect?

Bonus question: Why do brackets prevent the output of the background PID?

Comment: Reference: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408)

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1**

```
echo one && 
echo two & 
echo three && 
echo four
```

This can be rewritten as

```
echo one && echo two & 
echo three && echo four
```

The reason you get the `three` and `four` first is simply that it takes longer to get the subshell handling the `one` and `two` up and running than it does to print the `three` and `four`.

You can see this a little more clearly like this

```
echo one && echo two &
sleep 1
echo three && echo four
```

In this situation you get `one` and `two`, followed a second later by `three` and `four`.

Note that in the original scenario there is no guarantee that the `one` and `two` won't be mixed in with the output of `three` and `four`, conceiveably even with words being interpolated, such as `thonreee` or `twfouro`.

**Part 2**

```
echo one && 
(echo two &) 
echo three && 
echo four
```

This can be rewritten as

```
echo one && (echo two &) 
echo three && echo four
```

Here what is happening is that the `one` is printed immediately, and then the `two` is fired off in a subshell. Then (serially) the next line is executed, resulting in `three` and `four`. In your particular situation the subshell is small and fast enough that the `two` can be printed before the `three` is output. No guarantee of this, though, either.

**Part 3**

The brackets group statements together into a subshell. The ampersand `&` applies to a statement, but in this case you have used `&&` to link the two commands together so they have to be treated as a single statement.

Perhaps you should be using `echo one; echo two` rather than `echo one && echo two`? They are very different. The semicolon `;` separates two commands, which then run independently but sequentially. The double ampersand `&&` joins the two commands together as a *logical AND*, such that the second will only run if the first one completes successfully. Compare `false; echo yes`, `false && echo yes`, and `true && echo yes`. Then experiment by replacing `&&` (*logical AND*) with `||` (*logical OR*).

**Bonus**

You lose the job control notification because the subshell doesn't have job control.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> echo one && 
> echo two & 
> echo three && 
> echo four
> ```

Keep in mind that this is parsed like

```
echo one && echo two &
echo three && echo four
```

I'll assume that the `echo` commands are successful (they would only fail in edge cases such as redirection to a file on a full disk). So this snippet runs two tasks in parallel: one prints the lines `one` and `two`, and the other prints the lines `three` and `four`. The interspersing of `one` and `two` with `three` and `four` is not guaranteed and is likely to vary from system to system, from shell to shell and from invocation to invocation. For a toy example like this, you might observe reproducible results on a lightly-loaded system, but this is not something you can count on.

> ```
> echo one && 
> (echo two &) 
> echo three && 
> echo four
> ```

You've changed the parsing: here only the command `echo two` is executed in the background. This guarantees that `one` will be output first, and like before `three` will always be before `four`, but the placement of `two` could be anywhere after `one`.

The shell only prints a message about background processes if they're started from the main shell process, not when they're started in a subshell. Parentheses create a subshell, which is why `(echo two &)` doesn't cause the shell to print any message. This creates a background process, but not a background *[job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix))*.

> ```
> echo one && 
> (sleep 2 && echo two &)
> echo three && 
> echo four
> ```

In this snippet, the background job sleeps for 2 seconds before outputting `two`. This makes is extremely likely (but not actually guaranteed) that `two` will be output after `three` and `four`.